# in app purchase strange behavior

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

There was an error with the in-App-Purchase.

Requests are very long (>10 sec), and after the abolition of the request window appears several times: "enter your password".

The error is not stable, it appears and disappears on the iphone 3g. for ipad 3 and iPhone 4 does not have this error, even though requests are also very long.

It looks like a network problem, but with the Internet all right.
Everything worked fine a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your request will exactly generate one response so that following is called once:

```
productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveRespons
```

Check how many times your iPhone simulator hits this function - I am sure you can debug this part of the storekit.

Multiple sign-in prompts can only be caused if you generated and regenerated the product request in desperation.

Also, make sure you have signed out of your regular itunes account.
Once prompt comes in, sign in using sandbox userid that you created using itunes-connect website.

If you see long delays to hit didReceiveRespons, the only reason can be external delay and you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Long delays really happen in the network, other people's applications also have the same problem. Perhaps it is the fault of our ISP.
We test on multiple devices. The main problem is only on the iPhone 3g.
Error with multiple taps has been fixed before, problem not in it. Inquiry procedure is called once and generates a single request.
Thanks for your advice, we'll review how to generate queries.